# GenTux\Jwt\Drivers\JwtDriverInterface is not instantiable

Tags: jwt, access-token, lumen

BindingResolutionException

Target [GenTux\Jwt\Drivers\JwtDriverInterface] is not instantiable while building [App\Services\AuthService, GenTux\Jwt\JwtToken]

Answer (score 0):

By adding the below line in `bootstrap/app.php` at register service provider section solved my issue:

```
$app->register(GenTux\Jwt\Support\LumenServiceProvider::class);
```